# Premature termination of "Random Walk" program

Tags: c, arrays

[image]

[image]

This is my code for this question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main()
{
int i,move,move_count,row,col;
char ch = 'A',a[N][N];

for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
   for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
      a[row][col] = '.';

srand(time(NULL));
row = rand()%10;
col = rand()%10;
a[row][col] = ch;

for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    move = rand() % 4;
    move_count = 0;
    if(move == 0 && move_count < 4)                   //down
    {
        if(row+1 < 10 && a[row+1][col] == '.')
        {
           ch = ch + 1;    
           a[row+1][col] = ch;
           row += 1; 
        }
        else 
        {
           move = 2; 
           move_count++;
        }
    }

    if(move == 2 && move_count < 4)              //up
    {
        if(row-1 > 0 && a[row - 1][col] == '.')
        {
            ch = ch + 1; 
            a[row-1][col] = ch;
            row -= 1;
        }
        else 
        {
           move = 1; 
           move_count++;
        }
    }

    if(move == 1 && move_count < 4)             //left
    {
        if(col-1 > 0 && a[row][col-1] =='.')
        {
            ch = ch + 1; 
            a[row][col-1] = ch;
            col -= 1;
        }
        else 
        {
           move = 3; 
           move_count++;
        }
    }

    if(move == 3 && move_count < 4)             //right
    {
        if(col+1 < 10 && a[row][col+1] == '.')
        {
            ch = ch + 1; 
            a[row][col+1] = ch;
            col += 1;
        }
        else 
        {
           move = 0; 
           move_count++;
        }
    }
    if(move_count == 4)
    break;

}

for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
{
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
       printf("%c",a[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
}                                  
getch();
}
```

On Executing, sometimes it prematurely terminates without of the violation of condition `(b)`.Here is some screenshots of premature termination;
[image: o/p]
 [image]

One can see easily in first o/p,it terminates at `V` while in second it terminates on `Y`,although in both cases further movement is possible. 
Any idea how to get rid of from this?

**EDITED**
After my endless effort i have corrected this code(and yes without using an inner loop!).Thanks to  *`Thomas Padron-McCarthy`* & *`Ilmari Karonen`* for teir advise.
Edited code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main()
{
int i,move,move_count,row,col,seed=4;
char ch = 'A',a[N][N];

for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
   for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
      a[row][col] = '.';

srand((unsigned)seed);
//srand(time(NULL));
row = 0;//rand()%10;
col = 0;//rand()%10;
a[row][col] = ch;

for(i = 0; i < 26;)
{
    move = rand() % 4;

    if(move == 0)                                   //down
    {
        if(row+1 < N && a[row+1][col] == '.')
        {

           a[++row][col] = ++ch;
           i++;
        }

    }

    else if(move == 2)                              //up
    {
        if(row-1 >= 0 && a[row - 1][col] == '.')
        {
            a[--row][col] = ++ch;
            i++;
        }

    }

    else if(move == 1)                              //left
    {
        if(col-1 >= 0 && a[row][col-1] =='.')
        {
            a[row][--col] = ++ch;
            i++;
        }

    }

    else if(move == 3)                              //right
    {
        if(col+1 < N && a[row][col+1] == '.')
        {
            a[row][++col] = ++ch;
            i++;
        }

    }
    if((a[row+1][col]!='.'||row==9) && (a[row - 1][col]!='.'||row==0) && 
        (a[row][col-1]!='.'||col==0 )&& (a[row][col+1]!='.'||col==9) || i==25)
        break;        

}

for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
{
    for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
       printf("%c ",a[row][col]);
    printf("\n");
}                                  
return 0;
```

}

Comment: A tip: Use a constant to initialize the pseudo-random number generator, so you can re-run the same example several times when debugging.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy; By eliminating `srand(time(NULL))` from code i can do same.But how could this help to solve my problem?

Comment: start direction `move = rand() % 4;` It is not adapted to test the four directions therefrom.

Comment: Eliminating `srand` from the code will give you just *one* test case. He hinted how to create many. And he didn't answer the question, just posted a nice suggestion. That's what we have comments for.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy; I tried your idea and now understand what you are trying to say. Thanks sir for your valuable comment(I did't understand that at first glance).

Comment: (a) The examples in the question start at the top-left corner for A; it isn't clear whether that's the requisite behaviour. (b) The first output in black seems to stop at V, not Q (though it is still a premature stop). (c) You should only do one move per random number, but you have `move_count` to confuse things.If you can't move in the direction indicated by a specific random number, try a new random number. Note that in theory, you could end up with a sequence of random numbers that never generates the one direction available to move in. You should reduce the repetition in your code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; sorry for `Q` in place of `V`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're incrementing the move direction if the original direction is blocked, but the incrementing process goes only up to 3; it doesn't wrap around to 0 after that.  Thus, if, say, the original random direction you pick is 2, and both directions 2 and 3 are blocked, you never end up trying directions 0 and 1.

Two obvious solutions (which also guarantee a uniformly random choice of valid directions, unlike your method, which is biased in favor of the numerically first non-blocked direction) are to either:

- first check that there is at least one valid movement direction, and if so, keep picking random directions indefinitely until you find a valid one, or
- first make a list of all valid movement directions, and then pick a random element from it.

The second method is slightly (but not much) more complicated to implement, but it should also be faster, at least in cases where many adjacent squares are already filled.

Answer (score 3):

You have `for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)` with no internal loop.

This means you will have 26 *tries* and not 26 *moves*.

You need an internal loop, that will try to go in a random direction and will only exit if all 4 directions were checked.

Note: Counting the number of tries (`move_count`) is not going to work, as `rand` can give you the same direction multiple times.

Comment: "This means you will have 26 tries and not 26 moves" , +1 for this.

Comment: But how could i check for all four entries with an internal loop?
I tried before using `move_count` and it results in infinite loop!!!!!!

Comment: @haccks: One possibility is to generate a list of possible moves from the current position (0-4 numbers).  If you've got 0 moves, you're at the end.  If you've only got 1 move, make it.  Otherwise, choose one of the 2-4 moves at random.  So, create a function which analyzes the moves from the current position; use that to guide the decision making.  `int move_options(int curr_x, int curr_y, int *moves);` (optionally passing the main array too) will return a number 0-4, and if the return is not 0, `moves` will contain the available moves.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Sir, i have not read `functions` and `pointer`yet.

Comment: Not knowing how to write functions other than `main()` is a big problem, but we all go through that phase, I guess. Not knowing pointers can be survived (use `int moves[4]` in the argument list; the rest is unchanged).  Well, the code that should be in a function will have to be written out in the main program, I guess.  Perfectly doable, but sub-optimal (and it makes debugging less easy if you can't call a function to print the maze out).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main(void){
    int i, row, col;
    char ch = 'A',a[N][N];

    for(row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
            a[row][col] = '.';

    srand(time(NULL));
    row = rand()%10;
    col = rand()%10;
    a[row][col] = ch;

    for(i = 1; i < 26; i++){//already put 'A'
        enum { down, left, up, right };//0,1,2,3
        int move[] = {0,1,2,3};//Candidate in the moving direction
        int move_count, n;
        n = rand() % 4;//start direction
        move_count = 0;

        while(move_count<4){
            int gone = 0;
            n = (n + move_count) % 4;
            switch(move[n]){
            case  down:
                if(row+1 < 10 && a[row+1][col] == '.'){
                    a[++row][col] = ++ch;
                    gone = 1;//I was able to go forward.
                }
                break;
            case up:
                if(row-1 > 0 && a[row - 1][col] == '.'){
                    a[--row][col] = ++ch;
                    gone = 1;
                }
                break;
            case left:
                if(col-1 > 0 && a[row][col-1] =='.'){
                    a[row][--col] = ++ch;
                    gone = 1;
                }
                break;
            case right:
                if(col+1 < 10 && a[row][col+1] == '.'){
                    a[row][++col] = ++ch;
                    gone = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
            if(gone) break;
            ++move_count;//Number of times that I tried for a destination
        }
        if(move_count == 4){
            printf("No longer able to move\n");//need backtrack
            break;//give up!
        }
    }

    for(row = 0; row < N; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < N; col++)
            printf("%c",a[row][col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it was rewritten to correct about what i have pointed out in my comments.

Comment: still premature termination!!

Comment: Why  have you use `n = (n + move_count) % 4`?

Comment: @haccks `still premature termination` It is the same as the original. Judgment of the cul-de-sac or backtrack is required if you always go to the end.

Comment: @haccks Why? `n = (n + move_count) % 4` cycle through choice.